# Почему при выводе Integer.toBinaryString() для минимальных значений типов byte, short в Java выводится много лишних единиц?

Tags: java

C типом отрицательным Integer Все ясно - 32 разряда, одна 1 для знака.

А с  отрицательными byte и short чего так?!

И почему число меньшее нуля в этих типах из 32 разрядов?

```
1111111 = byte max
11111111111111111111111110000000 = byte min
111111111111111 = short max
11111111111111111000000000000000 = short min
1111111111111111111111111111111 = int max
10000000000000000000000000000000 = int min
```

Comment: byte - 8 бит, а short - 16

Comment: @Виктор да, но разве это влияет на такое количество ведущих единиц отрицательных чисел в двоичной форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в таких случаях происходит расширение типа `byte`/`short` до `int`, и выводится значение 32-битного числа.

Если нужно "обрезать" вывод, следует наложить битовую маску на 1 (`0xFF`) или 2 (`0xFFFF`) байта:

```java
byte bmin = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.printf("byte:  %32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(bmin & 0xFF));
System.out.println("-2^7:  " + Integer.toBinaryString(-128));

short smin = Short.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.printf("short: %32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(smin & 0xFFFF));
System.out.println("-2^15: " + Integer.toBinaryString(-32768));
```

```
byte:                          10000000
-2^7:  11111111111111111111111110000000
short:                 1000000000000000
-2^15: 11111111111111111000000000000000
```

Comment: Спасибо, это всё объясняет!